# how to call intent in index js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

How to call below intent in js, how to call "Default Welcome Intent" in the index.js file or in any other js files

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('How are you?');
});

exports.factsAboutGoogle = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: This is a really broad question. Have you setup an Action and you're having problems? Are you having problems using the simulator? Problems deploying this to Firebase? It isn't clear what you've tried or what errors you're getting

Comment: already , i have completed set-up actions and i can trigger main intent and Text intent. The code i have pasted is taken from online. "Default Welcome Intent" will be created in console of dialogFlow right? did i need to enable "Enable webhook call for this intent" to call this code in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make sure "Enable webhook call for this intent" is turned on for *each* Intent that you want to process through your webhook fulfillment.